# String index out of range, is there a proper way for comparing two strings?

Tags: char, string-comparison, indexoutofrangeexception, outofrangeexception

I have tried looking for the answer but as a beginner, there is only so much of java I can understand. I am trying to make the program be able to read individual chars and compare them with if statements.

```
    String Word1, Word2;
    char A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, A7, A8, A9, A10; 
    char B1, B2, B3, B4, B5, B6, B7, B8, B9, B10;
```

The strings must be from 6-10 characters so I made a bunch of chars, which I presume must be my problem as anything shorter than 10 will probably give me the Out of range issue.

Could someone tell me the proper way to compare the strings?

Answer (score 0):

you have several built-in functions in java for comparing two strings like String.equals() that tests for value equality.

Read [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/compare-two-strings-in-java/#targetText=Using%20String.equals()%20%3AIn,match%2C%20then%20it%20returns%20false.) how to use it.